# Vuetify remove the body title month and year element from date picker component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

initially the date picker component is like this:

[image: initial view]

I used the min, max props to disable all the other months except one so that the left and right icons are disabled and removed.

[image: current view]

What I want to do is, remove the month and year title in the body so that only weekdays are visible to the user. So the final thing would look something like this:

[image: final view]

is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, are you sure it might not be better to use the calendar component in monthly view instead?
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/
If it's for datepicker, it's not great usability wise to remove the header, it helps the user orientate themselves as well. If you still want to go through with it, the CSS hide below is probably your best bet, just make sure to limit it to the specific component rather than global. If you're doing a range, use the range option in datepicker btw rather than two.

Comment: You're correct. Its just that the use case  i am working on is a bit unusual and demands choosing date as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hide it with CSS:

```css
.v-date-picker-header {
  display: none
}
```

See [an example codepen here](https://codepen.io/morphatic/pen/Yzyqezx).

Comment: This works : ) Thank you very much. I wanted to ask how did you know to use v-date-picker-header,  so that I can solve any future problems like these.

Comment: I use the element inspector in Chrome. Right click on the element you want to know more about and select "Inspect" Then in the "Elements" pane, examine the HTML and find the outermost container element that I care about and look at the CSS rules that apply to that one. Glad it worked!

Comment: simple and effective solution.thank you mate...:)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `no-title` prop inside your date-picker. =D

Comment: Why was this not the accepted answer from the start?  +1 point for using pre-defined API props!

Comment: @eriegz it was not the accepted answer because it is not the correct answer. OP asked how to remove the month and year display which actually occurs in the _header_ of the component and not the _title_. The accepted answer is the correct answer because it properly solves the problem that OP had.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Since if you click on the month, you can choose the year, and ideally, I would like it to be impossible to choose the year at all.